Seek on gstreamer pipeline with multiple sources
I have a pipeline that plays audio from one source and video from the other.
    souphttpsrc name=VideoSrc ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
    souphttpsrc name=AudioSrc ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! volume name=Volume ! autoaudiosink

Everything works, except seeking. Audio is always played from the beginning, as if the pipeline restarted download.
What am I doing wrong?
(I'm using Python, but the question applies to any language.)
